# How to run sbt assembly by excluding integration test

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I am looking to create fat jar by 'sbt assembly' but i dont wan to run integration test in sbt assembly. I want only jar file.

Comment: `assembly / test := false`?

Comment: `assembly / test := {}` and this is the new default since [v1.0.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable tests in your `build.sbt` using `assembly / test := {}` as suggested by @laughedelic, or if you're executing from a terminal and want to skip to the tests for that build use: `sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' assembly`.

If you have set the value in your `build.sbt` file you can check that its value is as expected by running `sbt show assembly / test` which should return something like `()`.